# Preserve order of array elements in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` rendering custom `PeopleCell` `UITableViewCell` subclasses. I have a list of people `[A, B, C]` and they *have* to be displayed in that order. However when I render the cells in my table using:

```
var cell: PeopleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as! PeopleCell
```

the `UITableView` will render the cells out of order. Some times it's `B, C, A` or `C, A, B`, etc., you get the point. I remember having this problem in the past and I employed a temp solution of not using reusable cells since I'm rendering less than 5 cells at any point. I'd love some suggestions - thanks!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = cellIdentifier

        var cell: PeopleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as! PeopleCell

        let person = self.people![indexPath.row] as Person

        cell.lbl_name.text = nil
        cell.lbl_title.text = nil
        cell.btn_phone.setTitle(nil, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.btn_email.setTitle(nil, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.index = nil

        cell.lbl_name.text = person.contactName
        cell.lbl_title.text = person.title
        cell.btn_phone.setTitle(person.phoneNumber, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.btn_email.setTitle(person.emailAddress, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.index = indexPath.row
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
```

The datasource I'm using is simply a Swift array of `[Person]`

Comment: how are you populating your cell's contents, means what datasource are you using for this??

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information for us to understand your specific problem, so we have to give you a general answer.

The general answer is that cellForRowAtIndexPath needs to use a data model (usually an array) to hold the values that you want to display in each cell. If you have a sectioned table view, where there are both sections and rows, you might use an array of arrays where the outer array is your sections, and the inner arrays are the rows within each section.

When you dequeue a cell, remember that it was likely used previously to display a different entry in your array, so it has values in it's views that are wrong. You need to **FULLY** configure the cell, including setting fields that don't have a value to their empty/default state. If you don't empty out a view that you're not using, it might have a value from the last time it was used.

Recycled cells are kind of like paper forms. Imagine that a doctor's office reuses those stupid forms that it gives to new patients. The office hands a new patient a form with somebody else's information on it, and the new patient has to first erase EVERYTHING on the form before filling out their new info. If they don't, they might leave info about a disease that they don't have.

Recycled cells are like that. You have to erase the cell before installing new information in it, or at least replace the data in all the views in your cell with new data (or empty a view if you don't use it.) So, for example, if you have cells where some of them have images and some don't, you need to set a recycled cell's imageView.image to nil in case the previous use of the cell **did** install an image in the image view.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer, and great analogy. I apologize for the vague question and I've provided a code example. I tried using your technique of nullifying values before setting them but it didn't work.

Comment: what does "it didn't work" mean? What happens? Does it crash?